# need to convert individual sed commands into one single sed script

Tags: sed

The contents of my file are as follows and the desired output is shown below. Using individual sed commands, I am able to modify the file contents. Say

`sed -i -e 's!<tag1>FIELD1</tag1>!<tag1>Replaced contents of field1</tag1>! filename`

But I am having a tough time trying to replace those individual commands with a single sed script file.

`This is a sample file containing a few tags`

`<tag1>FIELD1</tag1>`
`<tag2>FIELD2</tag2>`

`<tag1>FIELD1 Do not change me</tag1>`
`<tag2>FIELD2 Do not change me</tag2>`

`<tag1>FIELD1 Do not change me</tag1>`
`<tag2>FIELD2 Do not change me</tag2>`

The desired output is

`This is a sample file containing a few tags`

`<tag1>Replaced contents of field1</tag1>`
`<tag2>Replaced contents of field2</tag2>`
`<tag2>Some addition to field2</tag2>`

`<tag1>FIELD1 Do not change me</tag1>`
`<tag2>FIELD2 Do not change me</tag2>`

`<tag1>FIELD1 Do not change me</tag1>`
`<tag2>FIELD2 Do not change me</tag2>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

The sed_script file (one single file)

`/<tag1>FIELD1<\/tag1>/s!<tag1>FIELD1</tag1>!<tag1>Replaced contents of field1</tag1>!

/<tag2>FIELD2<\/tag2>/c\

<tag2\>Replaced contents of field2</tag2>\

<tag2\>Some addition to field2</tag2>`

Answer (score 3):

You can chain the `-e` expressions.

For example:

```
sed -e 's!<tag1>FIELD1</tag1>!<tag1>Replaced contents of field1</tag1>!g' -e 's!<tag2>FIELD2</tag2>!<tag2>Replaced contents of field2</tag2>\n<tag2>Some addition to field2</tag2>!g' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tag=(  "tag1"          "tag2" )
find=( "FIELD1"        "FIELD2" )
repl=( "Replacement 1" "Replacement 2" )
regex=
I=$'\x01' # sed delimiter
for (( i=0; i<${#find[@]}; i++ )) ;do
    regex+="s$I<${tag[i]}>${find[i]}</${tag[i]}>$I<${tag[i]}>${repl[i]}</${tag[i]}>${I}g;"
done
sed "$regex" "$file"
```

You may or may not want or need the `g` at the end of each expression.